# For each character in string, read each one from right to left

Tags: java, pseudocode

I have this psuedocode, which converts a binary value to a decimal value:

```
int powTwo = 1;
int dec = 0;
for each character in the string, starting with the last,
if (char == '1')
    dec += powTwo;
    powTwo *= 2;
```

How do i write the for each loop specified here, which looks at each character in the string, starting with the last?
So far I have

```
for(Character c : someString)
```

Comment: Take a look at String.getBytes(). Or you could use a Vector to make it easier to iterate over the list of chars in reverse order.

Comment: you can use for loop instead to make it much simpler. do you require it only with for-each loop? it's doable but not as simple as regular for loop.

Comment: @jdv: That would look at it one *byte* at a time, not one *character* at a time. `charAt` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Long.parseLong(String s, int radix) or similar might simplify the job.

Comment: @Jon%20Skeet, right you are. Why would we ever need anything other than US-ASCII?

Comment: @jdv: What makes you think that `char` is US-ASCII? I'm really not sure what you're trying to say. But converting the string to a byte array is unnecessary anyway...

Comment: @Jon: http://www.computerworld.com/article/2534312/operating-systems/the--640k--quote-won-t-go-away----but-did-gates-really-say-it-.html

Comment: Why not keep it simple and do it from left to right?

Comment: @jdv: I fail to see how that's relevant. Basically, it's unclear whether you now genuinely think that `getBytes()` is a good idea, or whether you've changed your mind. (And why recommend `Vector` when `ArrayList` is more idiomatic?)

Comment: StringBuilder I think would be a better option than Vector myself. Just call its `reverse()` method and iterate with nothing complicated.

Comment: @Jon: I acknowledged your char/byte point and made a small joke related to how common this particular conflation can be. Nothing sinister. (Because, without checking the API docs, I knew that Vector had handy methods for picking stuff off the end. I couldn't quite remember if StringBuilder or ArrayList had the same methods I was thinking of.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume this is homework and you're supposed to stay true to the pseudo-code and not use other shortcut methods available.

Pretty much the only thing the pseudo-code is missing is the for-loop. In your real code, instead of using `for-in`, I would just walk the string backwards:

```
int powTwo = 1;
int dec = 0;
// using the length of the string, start with a counter that is the length
// minus 1, decrement it by 1 until we get to 0
for (int i = someString.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    // Get the character at position i in the string
    char currentChar = someString.charAt(i);
    // Check for a "1"
    if (currentChar == '1') {
        dec += powTwo;
    }
    powTwo *= 2;
}
```

Comment: var is not a valid Java keyword

Comment: Isn't .length a method? I think it need parentheses

Comment: Test and remove the bug: powTwo must be shifted at each iteration.

Comment: @jdv Even so it should not contain bugs.

Answer (score 2):

As said by [Cory](http://Cory) ,You can iterate from the last and compare each character.

An alternative approach is like this which literally has a **for each** loop as mentioned in your question

```
String reversedString=new StringBuffer(inputString).reverse().toString();
for(char c:reversedString.toCharArray()){
    // Do Whatever You want to Do here 
}
```

**For-each loop (Advanced or Enhanced For loop):**

The for-each loop introduced in Java5. It is mainly used to traverse array or collection elements. The advantage of for-each loop is that it eliminates the possibility of bugs and makes the code more readable.

Syntax of for-each loop:

```
for(data_type variable : array | collection){}
```

Comment: Even though you pretty much gave the same answer as me, I am giving you a +1 because of your explanation :-)

Comment: Thanks @Ascalonian , I haven't read your post before answering , otherwise there is no need for me to write ,As your answer more than enough .
and Yes thanks for +1 .. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [StringBuilder#reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()). You can reverse the `String` and just loop over each character without any confusing `for-loop`

```
String initialValue = "Hello World!";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(initialValue);

String reversed = sb.reverse().toString();

char[] chars = reversed.toCharArray();

for (char c : chars) {
    // Check for a "1"
    if (c == '1') {
        dec += powTwo;
    }

    powTwo *= 2;
}

// output: !dlroW olleH
```